# Filtering all rows in dataframe where at least one row meets a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a list of customers and the instances of products they have bought. I am trying to get a new dataframe that excludes all customers that have purchased a particular product at least once. For example:

```
d = {'Customer': ['Cust 1', 'Cust 1', 'Cust 2', 'Cust 1', 'Cust 2', 'Cust 2', 'Cust 3', 'Cust 3'], 
     'Product': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1], 
     'PO': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Output

```
| |Customer |Product   |PO        |
| |:--------|:---------|:---------|
|0| Cust 1  |  1       |  P1      |
|1| Cust 1  |  1       |  P2      |
|2| Cust 2  |  2       |  P3      |
|3| Cust 1  |  1       |  P4      |
|4| Cust 2  |  1       |  P5      |
|5| Cust 2  |  2       |  P6      |
|6| Cust 3  |  2       |  P7      |
|7| Cust 3  |  1       |  P8      |
```

I want to be able to filter out any customer that has purchased Product 2 at any stage, regardless of what else they have purchased, eg:

```
| |Customer |Product   |PO        |
| |:--------|:---------|:---------|
|0| Cust 1  |  1       |  P1      |
|1| Cust 1  |  1       |  P2      |
|2| Cust 1  |  1       |  P4      |
```

Is there a way to do this? Any help will be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it a couple of ways:

1. Using `groupby` with `filter` and `all`:

`df.groupby('Customer').filter(lambda x: (x['Product'] != 2).all())`

2. Using `groupby` with `transform` and `all` with boolean indexing:

`df[df.groupby('Customer')['Product'].transform(lambda x: (x != 2).all())]`

Output:

```
  Customer  Product  PO
0   Cust 1        1  P1
1   Cust 1        1  P2
3   Cust 1        1  P4
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, thanks for this! The transform function will work perfectly as it allows me to filter my data set and then apply the groupby on the output. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks again for that help - Im trying to apply this now but was wondering if you know a way that the actual dataframe can be filtered without using groupby?

Comment: No. because you want to return a group of records.  Now, you have had a condition that need to be met for all records then yes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.filter`:

```
new_df = df.groupby("Customer").filter(lambda x: 2 not in set(x["Product"]))
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  Customer  Product  PO
0   Cust 1        1  P1
1   Cust 1        1  P2
3   Cust 1        1  P4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
k = df[df['PO']=='P2']['Customer']
df[df['Customer'].isin(k)]
```

desired result

```
    Customer    Product PO
0   Cust 1          1   P1
1   Cust 1          1   P2
3   Cust 1          1   P4
```

Comment: I think you missed a `~` somewhere. You probably do not need the `.values` : ``df.loc[~df.Customer.isin(df.loc[df.Product == 2, "Customer"])]``

Comment: @sammywemmy; the values would also provide the correct result - but I agree with you - I removed it (old habit). thanks

Comment: In pandas, when you see '][' this is almost always a big no-no hinting to chained indexing.  Use .loc instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
df[~df.Customer.isin(df[df.Product == 2]['Customer'])]
```

Comment: In pandas, when you see '][' this is almost always a big no-no hinting to chained indexing. Use .loc instead